# Display data on grid view column programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a list of product quantity and a grid view. The grid view is already bind to some data. But I wanted to display the list of product quantity at the third column of grid view. Here is the code behind on how I bind the data to grid view:

```
gvProduct.DataSource = distSPUItem;
gvProduct.DataBind();
BoundField column = new BoundField(); 
column = new BoundField();
column.HeaderText = "Unit Quantity";
for (int index = 0; index < productQuantityList.Count; index++)
{
   column.DataField = index.ToString();
}
gvProduct.Columns.Add(column);
```

I need to loop thru the product quantity list and display the result at the third column of grid view. However, the column does not shows up. Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

**Edited Portion**

```
protected void gvProduct_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int unitQuantity = 0;
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for(int index = 0; index < productQuantityList.Count; index++)
            {
                unitQuantity = productQuantityList[index];
            }
            Label lblUnitQuantity = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblUnitQuantity");
            lblUnitQuantity.Text = unitQuantity.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `distSPUItem` and `productQuantityList`?

Comment: distSPUItem is retrieved from a class,             List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItem = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();. productQuantityList is integer type. Am I defining the new column in wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you do it in `RowDataBound` event. First you need to add the column and `OnRowDataBound="gvProduct_RowDataBound"` in the aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvProduct_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <!-- Existing columns here  -->
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUnitQuantity" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then set the text value of `lblUnitQuantity` in `gvProduct_RowDataBound` method in the code behind:

```
protected void gvProduct_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int unitQuantity = productQuantityList[e.Row.RowIndex];
        Label lblUnitQuantity = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblUnitQuantity");
        lblUnitQuantity.Text = unitQuantity.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note: `gvProduct_RowDataBound` will be executed for each row from the data source, so if `distSPUItem` has 10 items, then `gvProduct_RowDataBound` will be executed 10 times while incrementing `e.Row.RowIndex` value starting from 0. The above code will only work if `productQuantityList` and `distSPUItem` have the same number of items, otherwise it will be error.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  for more information regarding `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: I got a list of productQuantityList of 1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2. However, when I did in the RowDataBound method, it returns me all 2,2,2... Can you help me check the edited portion?

Comment: I must store the quantity in the list first because the list is retrieved from other parts of my code and it's really complicated.

Comment: Are you saying that the first row should be 1, second should be 2, third and fourth should be 1, and the rest should be 2?

Comment: Yup the productQuantityList is integer tho

Comment: It works. And ya, when I add the items into distSPUItem, I add the quantity into productQUantityList as well at my other parts of codes. But would you mind to explain a little bit on the RowDataBound method?

Comment: Added some explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to solve the problem this way:

Say you have a product item, something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }

    public Product(string data1, string data2)
    {
        Data1 = data1;
        Data2 = data2;
    }
}
```

If you want additional information, such as some kind of index, create class like this:

```
public class ProductExtended
{
    public string Data1 { get; set; }
    public string Data2 { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public ProductExtended(Product product, int index)
    {
        Data1 = product.Data1;
        Data2 = product.Data2;
        Index = index;
    }
}
```

Then convert list of Product items to a list of ProductExtended items:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
// ...

int i = 0;
List<ProductExtended> productsExtended = products.Select(p => new ProductExtended(p, i++)).ToList();
```

And finally bind that new list to your grid.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and I'd like to try it. However, there is a bunch of logic for my other part of codes to get the items in productQuantityList and I could not change them.