# How to display csv file data in unbound data grid view columns

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview

On a windows form I have two unbound data grid view columns each with their own header and I am trying read a csv file in a datatable and bind it to the grid.

Only I don't know the logic involved. I don't know how to bind the data to the 2 data grid view columns. There is a lot of samples out there of how to bind csv data to a grid view but they deal with headers that get read from inside a file and not unbound ones except for this but that's with asp. [Display data on grid view column programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869948/display-data-on-grid-view-column-programmatically)

Here is the data from the csv file.

```
Address,76 Douglas St Wakecorn
Property name,Wakecorn University
Building,C Block
Room,C2.18
```

Here is the code for the class that reads it.

```
    public class Setting
    {
        private DataTable _dt { get; set; }

        public DataTable ProcessSettingFileCMD(string filePath)
        {
            if (_dt == null)
            {
                populateControlWithCSVData(filePath);             
            }
        }

        private void populateControlWithCSVData(string filePath)
        {
            _dt  = new DataTable();            
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            if(lines.Length > 0)
            {
                for(int row = 1; row < lines.Length; row++)
                {
                    string[] dataWords = lines[row].Split(',');
                    DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();

                    foreach (string word in lines)
                    {
                        dr[word] = dataWords[row++];                        
                    }
                    _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the form

```
private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    openFD.ShowDialog(); 
    _dt = _objSetting.ProcessSettingFileCMD(openFD.FileName);

    if (_dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gvSettings.DataSource = _dt;
    }
}
```

The error being returned is here on `dr[word] = dataWords[row++];`

> System.ArgumentException: 'Column 'Address,76 Douglas St Wakecorn'
>   does not belong to table .

Comment: Does the data in the CSV repeat or is it just one record per file? Also, the format of your CSV is not standard in that each record is on multiple lines and starts with the header/name.  It would be easier to access the data if it was in `Address, PropertyName, Building, Room` format with each record on its own line

Comment: The first row of a CSV usually contains the Column Header (the columns' names). Use that header to create the Columns of your DataTable. Then, this is not the way to add a row: `dr[word] = dataWords[row++]; => dr[word]` either specifies the Column name or the column index. Not the current field content. Finally, the DataGridView Columns must already have their `DataPropertyName` property set to the corresponding DataTable Column name. You could also auto generate the DGV Columns, in this case. Or add them  in code, specifying the DataType, if needed.

Comment: The DataRow has a simplified constructor, which uses an `object[]` as source. It'll be an array of strings: you already have that, from `Split()`.

Comment: @haldo The CSV repeats. So it displays all data in the gridview. It originally had a loop that would print the first line in the CSV as headers which I took out because I already had the unbound columns. One unbound column was for the Description and another was for the Data. Both unbound columns have their own headers.

So Description could hold "Address" and Data could hold "76 Douglas St Wakecorn". 

That said, you're saying, it's easier to have `Address, Property name, Building, Room` as headers? I was hoping to have all that as csv values in the one column for Description.

Comment: @Jimi But I want to use the unbound columns I made in the designer as the headers. How can I do that? So I want to bind `Address, PropertyName, Building, Room` as values to the first column and `Douglas St Wakecorn, Wakecorn University, C Block, C2.18` as values to the 2nd column.

Comment: This is not a CSV file. It's a custom format you (or someone else) made up. Not a problem anyway, if the file contains just one block of informaitions. Or, if it contains more blocks of informations, all (always) taking 4 lines. You can read 4 lines at the time, `Split(`,`)` each line, adding the content of `dataWords[0]` to a string (string1) and the content of `dataWords[1]` to another (string2). Then, create a DataRow using (string1) as the first column's value and (string2) for the second column.

Comment: Note that you must add two Columns to the DataTable, using the same names you have set in the DGV's Designer as the `DataPropertyName` property. Otherwise, you'll end up with 4 columns instead of 2. If you don't, the ones you have set in the designer will be empty.

Comment: BTW, why don't you use a standard CSV format (with the fields names in the first line of the file)? It would solve most of your current and, probably, future problems.

Comment: @Jimi I burrowed someone's conventional format and then tried to customize it. The reason being because I want to map all the values in the "Data" column to rename a bunch of filenames in a drag drop box. 

The values would would be written to all of the files. I wanted to have the user create csv files at the touch of a button and read their contents to the gridview and print it to the filename. 
The Description header is just a meta data column should they be creating several files and forget what all the data is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the guidance and options provided I have taken out the columns made in the designer and instead instanced them when reading a CSV file.

Also I have used a CsvFileReader child class to bind it to a string list and then to a data table. Highly useful! http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c

Here is the rewritten code.

Settings Form.

```
public partial class frmSettings : Form
{

        protected string FileName;
        protected bool Modified;
        Setting _objSetting = new Setting();
        OpenFileDialog openFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

        public frmSettings()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            try
            { 
                openFD.Title = "Open a CSV File";
                if (SaveIfModified())
                {
                    if (openFD.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        _dt = _objSetting.ProcessSettingFileCMD(openFD.FileName);
                        if (_dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            gvSettings.DataSource = _dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
                FileName = openFD.FileName;
                Modified = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Error reading from {0}.\r\n\r\n{1}", FileName, ex.Message));
            }
            finally
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }            
        }
    }
```

Here is the Settings class again.

```
public class Setting
    {
        private DataTable _dt;
        DataColumn _dclColumnDescription = new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string));
        DataColumn _dclColumnData = new DataColumn("Data", typeof(string));

        public DataTable ProcessSettingFileCMD(string filePath)
        {
            if (_dt == null)
            {
                populateControlWithCSVData(filePath);                
            }
        }

        private void populateControlWithCSVData(string filePath)
        {            
            _dt  = new DataTable();
            List<string> columns = new List<string>();

            using (var reader = new CsvFileReader(filePath))
            {
                _dt.Columns.Add(_dclColumnDescription);
                _dt.Columns.Add(_dclColumnData);
                while (reader.ReadRow(columns))
                {                    
                    _dt.Rows.Add(columns.ToArray());
                }
            }            
        }
    }
```